# index.php is not loaded by default

Tags: php

my address is "http://www.dopsfest.com".

Written this way it shows javascript file (index.js)

If I add "/index.php" to the address - it is displayed correctly, i.e. - index.php is loaded.

I tried with php:

```
$address = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$stack = explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$file = array_pop($stack);
$folder = array_pop($stack);
if ($file =="") {header('Location: http://www.dopsfest.com/index.php');}
```

without success.

Why I need to write "index.php" ?
In localhost and on another remote server, it works without adding "index.php"

Comment: For a second, that almost looked like "dopeFest". *Ah, the 60's*

Comment: Have you tried configuring your server so that `index.php` is set as the default web page (along with `index.html`)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, and everything to do with the configuration of your webserver. Specifically the default document.

Comment: What server are you running? `Apache`, `Nginx`, `Lighttpd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apache**

Create a `.htaccess` file under the root of your project and put this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

**Nginx**

```
$ cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Index index.html index.htm, index.php;

**Lighttpd**

```
$ nano /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
```

```
index-file.names = ( "index.php", "index.html" )
```

Comment: Glad! Please consider accepting this answer as the best suitable for your question, especially if it solved your problem.